# How to create navbar like Google's Official blog navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was visit [Google Official Blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/), and interested with Google blog navbar and Header that is awesome ! i want make menu and the position like google blog's navbar the first position is relative and when scrolling be fixed but no idea to make it.

searching on google and never know it soz maybe google dev look it and give me information ;D or other people know it sharing please..

thanks,

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Tried Googling for "fixed position header?" Or anything?

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks I was trying some trick made by me but never like google ._. i think have problems

Comment: Try googleing "fixed-floating header" - here is a tutorial to get you started: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

Comment: Thanks @My Head Hurts i will try